# Angular change file name after compilation

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 15 web app, with this simple css in a component

```
.Bg_img1{
  background-image: url('../../assets/Images/foto_1.webp');
}
```

After ng build, Angular change the image name in foto_1.1e53a4e5f13f0a4b.webp and produce new image.
How disable this behaviour ?

I want my original file name and css

Answer (score 1):

In angular.json you has in

```
projects-->your-app-->architect-->build-->
     configurations-->production-->outputHashing
```

change the ouputHashing: "all" by "bundles" if only want to "hash" the .js and .css

BTW: see that the path of your .css it's related to "where your index.html is created" (the assets folder is simply `./assets`), so I imagine that the path should be `./assets/Images/foto_1.webp`

Comment: Thank's it works !

the strange thing i have another Angular (v 14) web app, with the same setting outputHashing="all" that not produce this behaviour

Comment: The "ouputHasing" is manage in different points, e.g. when you use in package.json the build can be like `"build": "ng build --output-hashing='all'"` (I'm now not pretty sure if override the angular.json). Check the differences between your two projects. Sorry, I can not help you much because I'm not much experience with this :(